# Where is the prototype property on strings in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, string

I just noticed that there is no prototype property on strings in [JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript).

This is a pedagogical question while I try to wrap my head around the JavaScript type system but what gives?

How come `"abc".toString()` works?  And how would I go about extending strings? If I wanted to be able to do `"hey you!".alertDialog()` for example?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
String.prototype.alertDialog = function() { alert(this); };
```

Answer (score 6):

String.prototype is the string prototype.

Comment: Whats the convention there anyways?

Comment: Every object should be capitalized : Object, String, Regexp, Number, Date, etc ...

Comment: The convention is that Constructors are capitolized. objects do not have to be capitolized, and should be, lest they be confused with Constructors

Comment: In my head I was thinking about constructors, not objects :)

Answer (score 3):

You can extend the String class by referencing

```
String.prototype.yourFunction = function() {}
```

Comment: And `this` inside the function will refer to the string the method is being called on.

Answer (score 2):

A word of warning when messing with prototype and Object data types, if you use a `for` loop, the full function will come back as one of the key/value pairs.  See the basic examples below and comments.

```
// Basic hash-like Object
var test = {
    'a':1,
    'b':2,
    'c':3,
    'd':4
};

// Incorrect
// badAlerter prototype for Objects
// The last two alerts should show the custom Object prototypes
Object.prototype.badAlerter = function() {
    alert('Starting badAlerter');
    for (var k in this) {
        alert(k +' = '+ this[k]);
    }
};

// Correct
// goodAlerter prototype for Objects
// This will skip functions stuffed into the Object.
Object.prototype.goodAlerter = function() {
    alert('Starting goodAlerter');
    for (var k in this) {
        if (typeof this[k] == 'function') continue;
        alert(k +' = '+ this[k])
    }
};

test.badAlerter();
test.goodAlerter();
```

Comment: Who's going to do a for loop on a `String`? And you should not use a `for in` with `Array`s either.  However, for maximum compatibility, it's best not to modify the prototype of native JS object